# Killing thread into qml plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qthread

I have a QML plugin which has a QThread inside. It is used to capture and display videoframes into the QMLview.

The problem is: how can I stop this thread when the window is closed?

**QML**

```
Repeater {
    model: 8

    CVCamScreen {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        url: Controller.urlCanal(index + 1)

        CustomBorder {
            commonBorder: true
            color: "#228e14"
            commonBorderWidth: 3
        }
    }
}
```

**C++ Component**

```
class CVCamScreen : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    CVCamScreen::CVCamScreen(QQuickItem *parent):
        QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
    {
        m_worker = new CamWorker(this);
    }

    CVCamScreen::~CVCamScreen()
    {
        m_worker->stop();
        delete m_worker;
    }

    private:
    CamWorker* m_worker; // inherits from QThread;
}
```

The current behavior is: the thread keeps running after the window is closed which means the CVCamScreen instances are not being destroyed.

Comment: CVCamScreen instance will be destroyed when its parent is destroyed. And CVCamScreen destroy the thread inside its destructor. Looks good, isn't it?

Comment: Can you confirm that `CVCamScreen`'s destructor gets called?

Comment: @folibis Shouldn't the CVCamSreen be destroyed after the window is closed? This is what I thought, but it is not what is happening.

Comment: @cmannett85 No it is not getting called. That is the issue it self.